# XSS safety - remove all scripts, allow everything else

Tags: javascript, html, xss, sanitization

We are displaying 3rd party HTML on our web page that should correctly render most things, including links and images.  We basically want to sanitize against all scripts, i.e.

```
<script>...</script>
```

But things can get pretty creative.  A simple case in which a script can show up outside of a 'script' tag is

```
<a href="javascript:alert('XSS')">
```

And we definitely need to allow links.

In fact as I'm sure many of you know, the problem is pretty brutal:  http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

If you're in a situation where users are posting comments to your website, you can just get away with escaping all HTML, or maybe escaping all HTML except `<em>`, `<i>`, `<u>` and `<s>`.  In my case we need to allow all HTML but disable all scripts which is much harder but not an uncommon requirement.  Is there a library or tool that supports this level of HTML-permissiveness and XSS-safety?

Language, in order of preference:  Python, PHP, Java, C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript (or jQuery) to either check before page submission that your href has the form http:// for any `<a>` tag using regex.

Comment: *"Language, in order of preference: Python, PHP, Java, C/C++."* Client side validation is nice to have, but never the final solution - and to boot you did not provide any examples.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, that site lists down only whole XSS injections. Methods similar to [`strip_tags`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will not work with fragmented (multi-point) injection, which I consider more stealthy. The best you can do is encode your characters with something like [PHP's `htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) before displaying them to a page. But that would prevent HTML from being displayed.

You could do alternative markup, like how forums do it (the ones with `[code][/code]` syntax). Also consider using [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), the same editor used here in StackOverflow, which is easy to use if you only need text formatting.

Comment: We're compiling third party HTML so this won't work.  We really do need nearly all the capabilities of HTML, save scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the PHP framework, CodeIgnitor?

There's a security class that includes the xss_clean() function and more that looks to handle your needs pretty closely.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html

Comment: This may work.  I didn't specify in the question but we want to knock out non-malicious scripts as well, so may use this in conjunction with that technique.

Comment: Use HTLPurifier instead. Codeigniter's XSS cleaning is blacklistbased which makes it almost certain that things can get through. And it blocks words like alert which in itself does not pose a risk if executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest nothing less than the most robust XSS prevention you can find. In general, the best approach is to whitelist elements and attributes (and values) that you want to allow rather than blacklist the ones you don't.

I can only offer a PHP based solution in [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which in addition to security, helps ensure your markup is valid (great for user-submitted HTML snippets).

I see you've found http://ha.ckers.org/ -
 I also suggest using [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) (Open Web Application Security Project) as a resource.

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion for how to whitelist "href" while still knocking out scripts?

Comment: I believe you would do this with a [URI.AllowedSchemes](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#URI.AllowedSchemes) whitelist, but I haven't used it in years. Or do you mean in general, without HTMLPurifier? What other tools have you considered?

Comment: Don't forget all the other nasty stuff, like `<object>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>`, `<applet>`, click hijacking, and other annoyances like `<audio>`, `<video>`, stray end tags or open comment delimiters that break the page.. there's a lot to be concerned about. Wish I knew more about the context, but I guess if you want only minimal security, just use something weak like a string replace or regex. If you want tight security you should use established third party scripts.

Comment: Context is loading an arbitary email into a web page.  Want everything that gmail would display and nothing it wouldn't (e.g. scripts).  I don't really know how crazy this is to do safely.

Comment: Even Gmail has been found to have XSS holes: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/12569/4516, but I get what you're after. I would try out HTMLpurifier or HTMLTidy with the Codeigniter XSS function in the other answer (make sure to look at the source, of course). This is really tricky business, I would tend to disallow quite a bit to be on the safe side. It also kind of depends on the source of the content; where does it come from? It's "arbitary email"? I don't get it.